# requests.post with Authentication giving error 415 for jira rest api in python

Tags: python, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

```
url = "https://example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/issue_key/comment"
data = json.dumps({"body": 'some string'})
headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

-->  `r.status_code` output is `415`.

But in case of

```
r = requests.get(url, data, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

-->  `r.status_code` output is `200`. Please help me to identify issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot to add the headers variable to your post requests. thats why it fails. just add this to your post request and you should get a 201 status code as response:

```
r = requests.post(url, data, auth=('username', 'password'), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

The server application probably doesn't process `application/json` so when you send it json data it returns `415` error

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)

The GET request seems to work but it may just be sending back a login prompt. POST the data in a format that the server application can process.

Comment: thanks for help but even for simple string without json it will give same string                           
url = "https://example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/issue_key/comment"
data = "PR raised"
r = requests.post(url, data, auth=('username', 'password'))

Comment: I see a 404 error. Can you share the same url you are working with, and are 'username' and 'password' actual values or placeholders for them.

Comment: thanks a lot..below one is working fine..actually i missed headers=headers.....once again thanks